# Neural Network for regression problem has loss greater than 9000

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I've made a NN with 15 features or columns with each feature/column ranging from -50 to +100 and the output should always be positive.

The problem is with the loss and accuracy, with each epoch loss is very big

The code is given below:

```
td = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
tg = train_data.pop('RESULT')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((td.values, tg.values))
td = dataset.shuffle(len(td)).batch(1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
model.fit(td, epochs=100)
```

Comment: What is the task? Classification or regression?

Comment: predict the result and the result can be any number greater than 0 @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: That does not really answer my question, classification means the output is discrete, while regression means that the output is continuous, which of these is your task?

Comment: Then you should use mean squared error as loss, not binary crossentropy, which is a classification loss

Comment: Ok, and? Also accuracy is a classification-only metric, it does not make sense to use it for regression.

Comment: You cannot tell if the value of MSE in itself is "big" or "small"; it depends crucially on the *scale* of your true values: if, for example, your true values are in the hundreds (or even tens) of thousands, an MSE of 9000 is not bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Regression, I think the use of Mean Squared Error is good. I'm not surprised the loss is so high because of the large variance of the possible target values. I would suggest finding a way to scale the values to bring the variance closer to 1, perhaps by applying the log function. Also, since your inputs contain values varying from -50 to +100, I'd also recommend scaling those values to something like [-1, 1].

Comment: Converting values to [-1,1] will affect the result

Comment: @SharadRaj what do you mean? Can you not scale the inputs?

Comment: It's fine now, I've made some changes to the model